# Google Analytics collect and visualize custom data

Tags: android, analytics, google-app-engine

I was wondering if Google Analytics (GA) can be used to collect custom metadata about app usage and performance.

An example would be to measure and collect the average frame rate (fps) of the app on the device. How can this data be presented into the Google Analytics Report? If possible, please make an example by sample source code.

Comment: I recall there were similar tool specifically tailored to games e.g. gameanalytics (Tablet mostly?). Maybe there are more.

Comment: Can you provide some kind of a list of references?

Comment: Just google search: "analytics for games" and alike.

Comment: Seems like there are a couple of popular choices: gameanalytics, flurry analytics, localytics.